# Bokeh labelling a slope with legend

Tags: python, annotations, bokeh, legend

I am doing a simple 1D linear regression model and am plotting my line of best fit as a slope using Bokeh. The problem is that I want to display two lines of best fit, one from SKLearn and the other from my own gradient descent code. I want to display these lines with a legend but can't seem to figure out how to label a Slope in Bokeh.

I want to keep using the Slope annotation feature as it extends beyond the extent of the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Here x is my x-data and y is my y-data

theta_GD = np.array([[-3.63029144],[ 1.16636235]]) # my fitting gradient descent parameters
theta_SK = np.array([[1.19303364],[-3.8957808783]]) # fitting parameters from SKLearn

fig = figure()

gradient_GD = theta_GD[1]
y_intercept_GD = theta_GD[0]

gradient_SK = theta_SK[1]
y_intercept_SK = theta_SK[0]

slope1 = Slope(gradient=gradient_GD, y_intercept=y_intercept_GD, line_color='red', line_width=2)
slope2 = Slope(gradient=gradient_SK, y_intercept=y_intercept_SK, line_color='blue', line_width=2)

fig.scatter(x,y)
fig.add_layout(slope1)
fig.add_layout(slope2)
show(fig)
```

Comment: Please change your opening post and add your code to the question so we can see what you are doing and where we can help improve your code.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post with a snippet from my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you draw your fitted lines as Line glyphs instead of  Slope annotations. For example:

```
m, b= 3,1
m1, b1 = 3.2, .8
x = np.linspace(-10,10,100)
data = m*x + b + np.random.normal(0,3,size=len(x))
y = m*x + b
y1 = m1*x+b1
fig = figure()
fig.line(x,y,legend_label='My Regression',color='green',line_width=2)
fig.line(x,y1,legend_label="Other Algorithm",color='red',line_width=2)
fig.scatter(x,data)
show(fig)
```

which yields:
[image]

Comment: It's definitely possible to use a `Slope` for the annotation and manually at add/use a line for the legend, but it's a bit tedious to set up. I think we can probably do better and make it much easier to add legend entries for annotations. I'd really suggest making a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issue) to discuss it.

Comment: For my own interest, what's the advantage of using a Slope annotation as opposed to just drawing the line?

Comment: Slope annotation is "infinite", which may or may not be an advantage, depending on your use case.